# Why the test past with any numbers even if the result isn't 3?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I start with Mockito and in the tutorial there is this test:

```
@Test
public void calculate_shouldUseCalculator_forAnyAddition() {
    // GIVEN
    final Random r = new Random();
    when(calculator.add(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(3);

    // WHEN
    final int result = classUnderTest.calculate(
            new CalculationModel(CalculationType.ADDITION, r.nextInt(), r.nextInt())).getSolution();

    // THEN
    verify(calculator, times(1)).add(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class));
    verify(calculator, never()).sub(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class));
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

I don't understand why the test past. The result of the addition of two any integer isn't always 3.

Comment: You have stubbed the `add ()` method to return 3 no matter what integers you pass to it. That is what the `when().thenReturn()` does

Comment: But you're literally telling it to return `3` if you add any two integers in the "GIVEN" part.

Comment: So thenReturn obligate the result to be 3 whatever the parameters of the function.thank you!

Comment: @Mitch Yes, that's the main feature of mocking. You tell some methods to return the result you want. And then make sure another methods (the ones you test) work properly assuming the mocked ones are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of your unit test is to make sure the method `add` is subsequently called for any `CalculationModel` with calculation type parameter equal to `CalculationType.ADDITION`.

You don't really care whether the `calculator.add()` method itself works properly. The only thing you should check if it's been called by `calculate` method. Thus you mock its result with a constant for any parameters:

```
when(calculator.add(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(3);
```

Now you assert that whenever the `calculate` is called with `CalculationType.ADDITION`, the result is equal to the constant you defined.

---

Consider this syllogism:

**If**:

A. `calculate` calls `add`

B. `add` returns 3

**Then**:

C. `calculate` returns 3

Comment: Thank for the update ^^, Yes, so whatever the function return for result, the mock test only if the function is calles, but not is the result is correct allows the parameter. The call of the "classUnderTest.calculate(
            new CalculationModel(CalculationType.ADDITION, r.nextInt(), r.nextInt())).getSolution();" return always 3 because thenReturn parameter that even if the real function return another value ?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, the `calculator.add(...)` returns whatever you told it to return. In this particular unit test it's 3, but could be other value, depending on your needs.